# Concurrent hash-tables

Tags: hash, concurrency, hashmap, hashtable

I make some investigation about a hash-tables implementations for multi-threaded environment. I wonder are there some new articles or research in 2010-2014 period? Maybe you know about such scientific papers?

Currently, I've found not so much information about it:
 1. [Relativistic Causal Ordering A Memory Model for Scalable Concurrent Data Structures](http://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/open_access_etds/497/)
 2. [CPHash: A Cache-Partitioned Hash Table](http://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/metreveli-cphash-tr.pdf)

Comment: Not sure, but is this what you're looking for? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html

Comment: I'm looking for new articles about concurrent hash-tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into Cuckoo Hashing and Hopscotch Hashing?

Comment: Yes, I've read about them. I wanted to find some info about "cutting-edge" implementations of concurrent hash tables. Thank you for your response, anyway.